# Grails define mapping property in has many relationship

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm, many-to-one

i have two domain classes with has many mapping.

One class :

```
class Line  {

static belongsTo = [header : Header]

Long invoiceId
Long lineNumber
Long oneId
Long secondId
Long thirdId

static mapping = {
    table('LINES_2_V')
    version(false)
    id composite: ['invoiceId', 'lineNumber']
}
```

}

another class :

```
class Header {

static hasMany = [lines: Line]
Long id

static mapping = {
    table('HEADERS_2_V')
    version(false)
    id column:'INVOICE_ID'
}
```

}

Createria :

```
Header.createCriteria().list() {

createAlias('Lines', 'l', CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)

if (oneId) {
    eq('l.oneId', oneId)
} else {
    isNull('l.oneId')
}
if (secondId) {
    eq('l.secondId', secondId)
}else {
    isNull('l.secondId')
}
if (thirdId) {
    eq('l.thirdId', thirdId)
}else {
    isNull('l.thirdId')
}
```

}

and i get following error :

```
ORA-00904: "L1_"."HEADER_ID": invalid identifier
```

Hibernate generated select looks like this :

```
Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.INVOICE_ID as INVOICE1_0_1_
from HEADERS_2_V this_, 
LINES_2_V ihl1_ where this_.INVOICE_ID=l1_.header_id and ihl1_.project_id is null 
and ihl1_.transaction_id is null and ihl1_.po_header_id is null ) where rownum <= ?
```

why it is trying to map by `HEADER_ID` ? how to make it to map by `INVOICE_ID` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is your back reference to Header that is stored in Line table. Your tables are like this:

> Lines_2_V : invoice_id,   line_number,   **header_id**,   one_id,   second_id ,thid_id
>
> Header_2_V:  invoice_id

Since Gorm already has Header's `id` stored in Line table, its using that to join them.

When you have `belongTo` as a map:

```
static belongsTo = [header : Header]
```

Grails/Gorm will create a back reference in your table. You can also use

```
 static belongsTo =  Header
```

Which gorm creates intermediate table to join them
for more information refer to GORM Gotchas article by [Peter Ledbrook](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)

---

btw, `Lines` should be `lines`:

```
createAlias('Lines', 'l', CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
```

should be

```
createAlias('lines', 'l', CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
```

Comment: thanks, you have opened my eyes, i needed to use uni-directional many to one relationship, because only header cares about lines. From line i don't need to reach header. Thanks, you saved my life.